# no existe la función <<_insert_clients(unknown...)>> Ninguna función coincide en el nombre y tipos de argumentos. ¿Qué significa este error?

Tags: postgresql

Deseo insertar datos a una tabla por medio de una función, sin embargo siempre recibo el mismo error y no sé que significa. Les agradecería su ayuda.

Revisé una y otra vez los tipos de datos que utilicé, sin embargo el mismo error se mantiene. A continuación la función que creé y cómo la ejecuto.

```
CREATE FUNCTION _insert_clients(_pname VARCHAR(30), _psurname   VARCHAR(30), _pcanton VARCHAR(30),
                                _pprovince VARCHAR(15), _pemail1 VARCHAR(30), _pemail2 VARCHAR(30),
                                _ppassword VARCHAR(30), _pphone INT, _pdescription  VARCHAR(500),
                                _pphoto BYTEA)
RETURNS INT AS $$

BEGIN
            IF EXISTS(          ---If client's title exists, doesn't insert
            SELECT Client._email1
            FROM Client
            WHERE _pemail1 = Movie._email1
            ) THEN

        RETURN -1;

    ELSE

    DECLARE
        _countClientID INT := COUNT(*) FROM Client; ---Increases client's ID
        _tempID INT :=((_countClientID) + 1);

    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Client(_id, _name, _surname, _canton, _province, _email1, _email2, _password, _phone, _description, _photo, _isActive)  ---Inserts into movie
        VALUES(_tempID, _pname, _psurname, _pcanton, _pprovince, _pemail1, _pemail2, _ppassword, _pphone, _pdescription, _pphoto, true);
        RETURN _tempID;
        END;
        END IF;
END $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT _insert_clients('Pamela', 'Hernández Rivera','Turrialba', 'Cartago', 'pame@gmail.com',0, 'pamela3', 87965432,'Soy chica',pg_read_binary_file('C:\PERRITO.jpg'));
```

Lo que deseo es que se inserte este cliente a la tabla Client.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba la siguiente forma de llamar a la función, haciendo casting explícito:

```
SELECT _insert_clients(
    'Pamela'::VARCHAR(30),
    'Hernández Rivera'::VARCHAR(30),
    'Turrialba'::VARCHAR(30),
    'Cartago'::VARCHAR(15),
    'pame@gmail.com'::VARCHAR(30),
    'pame2@gmail.com'::VARCHAR(30),
    'pamela3'::VARCHAR(30),
    87965432,
    'Soy chica'::VARCHAR(500),
    pg_read_binary_file('C:\PERRITO.jpg'));
```

Parece raro al principio, pero en PlpgSQL, no es lo mismo una cadena en crudo que un campo `VARCHAR`. Para comprobar si estás realizando bien el casting de tipos, puedes ejecutar la función `pg_typeof`:

```
select pg_typeof('hola') as cadena_en_crudo,
       pg_typeof('hola'::TEXT) as texto,
       pg_typeof('hola'::VARCHAR(30)) as campo_de_largo_variable;
```

El error significa que no estás pasando los tipos de argumentos correctos.